# secondaryHash(Object key) implementation explanation

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is a method from a `HashMap` implementation from `java.util` package:

```
static int secondaryHash(Object key) {
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    hash ^= (hash >>> 20) ^ (hash >>> 12);
    hash ^= (hash >>> 7) ^ (hash >>> 4);
    return hash;
}
```

Can somebody explain what are these `^=`, `>>>`, `^` things are and what's going on here?

Comment: Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: `^` is a bitwise XOR and `>>>` is an unsigned right shift. `^=` has the same meaning as `+=` but with the bitwise XOR.

Comment: What implementation do you explore? HotSpot's `HashMap` don't have `secondaryHash()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x ^= y` : is the short hand operator for `x = x ^ y`.

`^` : is the binary exclusive-or operator **XOR**.

`y >>> x` : is the binary shift operator which shifts all bits of **y** **x**-bits to the right while filling in **0**-bits to the left. This means the sign will not be preserved if the initial value was a negative number.

Comment: +1 for you. I'm going to stop answering questions tonight. :P If your answer gets accepted I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator performs a [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) of two integer quantities.

The `^=` is similar to `+=` except for `^`.

The operator `>>>` is a logical right shift, which moves each bit towards the right, removing those bits that fall off the right. On the left `0`'s are filled in.

```
static int secondaryHash(Object key) {
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    hash ^= (hash >>> 20) ^ (hash >>> 12); // Set hash to equal to bitwise XOR of it with itself right shifted by 20 and right shifted by 12.
    hash ^= (hash >>> 7) ^ (hash >>> 4);   // Same thing for right shift by 7 and right shift by 4.
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: **^** is not OR but XOR!